# Linux Modify/Add Kernel Command Line from InitramFS "UserSpace"

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I am developing an embedded Linux device. I have successfully created an InitramFS CPIO archive that runs quickly after boot. Now, I want to change the initial kernel command line to include "quiet" parameter so I can boot even faster.

However, once the splash screen is displayed in the InitramFS, I want to remove the quiet option for the kernel so the remainder of the boot is NOT quiet.

How can I achieve this? How can I reverse the initial "quiet" kernel command line option once I've reached the InitramFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really change the kernel command-line after boot, but what you *can* do is reproduce the effects of setting or unsetting the `quiet` command-line through other means, which should accomplish what you want to achieve here.

In short, to increase verbosity once you don't want `quiet` anymore, you can use this command:

```
# echo 7 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

And to emulate what `quiet` does, this is what you can use:

```
# echo 4 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

This should take care of the kernel side of the setting... But sometimes userspace will also change behavior based on this kernel option. For instance, systemd will parse the `quiet` option in the kernel command-line, and act as if `ShowStatus=auto` was used in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. If you want to revert that (to enforce the default and ignore the `quiet` option), edit that config file and uncomment the `ShowStatus=yes` line there, which should take care of it.

There might be other systems in userspace that look at this option, so you might need to take a closer look at those to see how they behave and how to reproduce (or undo) the behavior of the option being present in the kernel command-line.

The following is a deep dive into the sources to explain the behavior of the `quiet` option in the kernel and systemd.

---

The kernel parses the `quiet` option by calling the [`quiet_kernel()` initialization function](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c?h=v4.18#n220), which does:

```
static int __init quiet_kernel(char *str)
{
    console_loglevel = CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_QUIET;
    return 0;
}

early_param("quiet", quiet_kernel);
```

The `console_loglevel` pseudo-variable is actually the [first element of the `console_printk` array](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/printk.h?h=v4.18#n65):

```
extern int console_printk[];

#define console_loglevel (console_printk[0])
```

Log level ["quiet" is defined as 4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/printk.h?h=v4.18#n50):

```
#define CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_QUIET   4 /* Shhh ..., when booted with "quiet" */
```

A few lines below, the [default log level](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c?h=v4.18#n63) is defined through a kernel config:

```
/*
 * Default used to be hard-coded at 7, we're now allowing it to be set from
 * kernel config.
 */
#define CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT
```

And that kernel config is [set in Kconfig.debug, still defaults to 7](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/Kconfig.debug?h=v4.18#n18):

```
config CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT
    int "Default console loglevel (1-15)"
    range 1 15
    default "7"
```

(You might want to check that your kernel is using the default config, either in `/boot/config-*` or in `/proc/config.gz`.)

And for more details on using `/proc/sys/printk`, see the [kernel documentation for it](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt?h=v4.18#n739). But, in short, it is possible to write only a single number, in which case only the first element of the array will be updated, which is what you want here.

---

systemd will also parse the kernel command-line, looking for entries typically named `systemd.*`, but it turns out [systemd also recognizes the `quiet` kernel command-line](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/core/main.c#L471) and uses it to set the ShowStatus:

```
    } else if (streq(key, "quiet") && !value) {

            if (arg_show_status == _SHOW_STATUS_UNSET)
                    arg_show_status = SHOW_STATUS_AUTO;
```

In this case, it will only set it if it wasn't previously set (`_SHOW_STATUS_UNSET`) and will set it to "auto" (`SHOW_STATUS_AUTO`.)

Another way to set the ShowStatus is [through the configuration file](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/core/main.c#L655):

```
            { "Manager", "ShowStatus",                config_parse_show_status,      0, &arg_show_status                       },
```

This line describes the configuration option named `ShowStatus=` under the `[Manager]` section of `system.conf`. The [parser for this option](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/core/show-status.c#L12) takes either the "auto" string (in which case it sets it to `SHOW_STATUS_AUTO`) or takes a boolean, which can be "yes", "true" or "1" to enable it, or "no", "false" or "0" to disable it.

The [systemd documentation for `--show-status=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#--show-status=) is also pretty helpful here. It cites the `ShowStatus=` configuration too (since passing systemd command-line arguments directly is not always easy to do, updating a configuration file is definitely a more straightforward way to configure this setting.)

---

I hope you find this helpful and that it helps you accomplish the right verbosity for your particular use case!